# Yellow tinge to screen after installing elementary OS

Tags: display

I have just installed elementary OS Hera 5.1 on my 2011 Macbook Pro. I have noticed that my screen now has a yellowish tinge to it. It goes back to normal after a while so at first I thought it might be ageing hardware but after a quick look online I see that a few other people have experienced a similar problem albeit on different distros. This is my first time using linux (also my first time posting) so I apologise if the solution is a simple one.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Elementary has a *night light* feature which removes a lot of blue light from the display, outside the hours of daylight. This can be customised or disabled completely.

Go to the **Applications** section, and find the **System Settings** tool. Within Systems Settings, choose **Displays**. Click the **Night Light** section and you are presented with an option to turn off this feature if required.

[image: night light settings on elementary]

Comment: Thank you Simon B. That was the exact feature. Thank you for taking the time to answer me!

Comment: that's good news. please upvote and click "accept answer" for future users.